# redux reselect is returning a function

Tags: reactjs, redux, reselect

For some strange weird reason my reselect selector is returning this function :

```
ƒ () {
    if (!areArgumentsShallowlyEqual(equalityCheck, lastArgs, arguments)) {
        // apply arguments instead of spreading for performance.
        lastResult = func.apply(null, arguments);
    }
```

I do not understand why it is doing this. It is supposed to return some JSON which I can use to map in my **mapToProps**.

My redux mapping is simple enough and looks like this :

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        initialValues: selectShop(state),
    }
}
```

My selector file looks like this :

```
import { createSelector } from 'reselect';

//shops selector
const selectDomain = () => state => (state ? state.shops : {});

export const selectShop = () =>
    createSelector(
        selectDomain(),
        shops => {
            let shop = shops.filter(shop => shop.selected);
            return shop[0];
        },
    );
```

Why am I getting a function returned instead of JSON?

Comment: Nothing "strange" `createSelector` creates selector function. :)

Comment: am I supposed to write my mapToDispatch code like this : initialValues: () => selectShop(state),

Comment: No. You need to reimplement `selectShop` to be the result of `createSelector` call.

Comment: ok looks like I'm getting confused with my 'create' and 'select' functions again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `createSelector` wrong. It actually returns a memoized version of a function.

Something like this should work

```
import { createSelector } from 'reselect';

//shops selector
const selectDomain = state => (state ? state.shops : []); // I've fixed it to return an array 

export const selectShop = createSelector(
  selectDomain,
  // you could use find instead of `filter` herr
  shops => shops.find(shop => shop.selected)
)
```

Comment: For clarity, the OP was facing issues because he was **returning** a createSelector function, when he should have been setting his `selectShop` variable to the result of the createSelector.  Returning the createSelector returns a memoized function, while returning the result of the createSelector gets the value.

Answer (score 1):

Also to add to the accepted answer. The selector is being called wrong. This is how it should be called correctly :

```
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    let selector = selectShop()

    return {
        initialValues: selector (state),
    }
}
```